# How to use plist log file debug

Tags: ios, debugging

I got a plist file from my user, but I don't know how use use it to debug, can somebody tell me how to use the plist log file to debug?

Comment: Is it a crash log or low memory report?

Comment: it's a crash log file, I never use it, so can you tell me how to use it to find bug

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash report. Take a look how to do this: [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports?rq=1). Once you symbolicate you can figure out what is the reason. Not sure it will have sufficient information to pin point but that's a start. You can come back here and update your question with additional info.